# Get the return value from a function

Tags: c, char

I want to modify a char by using a function and print it on the screen but my code cannot achieve this function. Here is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
long M = 2147483647;
void IntroduceError(char k[],double p)
{
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if ((double)random()/M <= p)
            k[i] = 1;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char test[] = "11110000";
    double rate = atof(argv[1]);
    IntroduceError(test, rate);
    printf("\nErrored codeword is : %s\n",test);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It won't even compile.

Comment: What is `get`? What is your expected output for what command line?

Comment: Do you mean `printf("\nErrored codeword is : %s\n",text);` instead of `printf("\nErrored codeword is : %s\n",get);`? also notice that `argv[1]` is a string and your function is expecting a `double`, use  `printf("\nErrored codeword is : %s\n",strtod(text, NULL));`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Now it can compile but I cannot modify the char test. I want to modify the each bit of  test when the random number is less than 0.01

Comment: `2147483647` should be replaced with `RAND_MAX`, `random` with `rand`, and `k[i]=1` with `k[i]='1'`.  If I make those changes and use a sufficiently high rate argument, your program does what you expected it to do.

Comment: (Also you seem to be confused about the difference between bits and `char`s.)

Comment: @zwol I modified the 2147483647 should be replaced with RAND_MAX random with rand, and k[i]=1 with k[i]='1',  and I got the right output. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`k` is a string i.e. array of characters, but you're assigning an integer value to it.

Instead of:

```
k[i] = 1;
```

You probably want:

```
k[i] = '1';
```

Also, you should call `srandom` at the start of your program to seed the random number generator, passing in at least the PID, i.e. `srandom(getpid());` so that you don't get the same results every time.

Answer (score -1):

`get` in the `printf` statement is not defined. If you change `get` with `test` it should compile.

Comment: I assume it is because you didn't answer the question.

Comment: The code wouldn't even compile until you fixed the code that I mentioned, then the code was fixed exactly what I said, and that gets a negative rating. Something is wrong with this site if that's how things work.

Comment: It looks like the my negative rating was given by a person that doesn't even know the correct variable name "test" not "text"